# cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to matmul_rec.exe.stackdump

Tags: c, recursion, exception, cygwin, matrix-multiplication

I am rather new to C language, I'm trying to implement a recursive block matrix multiplication for this assignment I'm working on, but I keep getting this error, I couldn't find anywhere on the internet any solution.

```
'''
/*
 * Matrix-matrix product W += U*V
 * U has dimension m * n
 * V has dimension n * l
 * W has dimension m * l
 */
void gemm_rec(int m, int n, int l, int srU, int scU, int srV, int scV, int srW, int scW, double *U, double *V, double *W, int block_num)
{
    if (block_num > 4)
    {   
        block_num /= 4; 
        m /= 2;
        n /= 2;
        l /= 2;

        gemm_rec(m, n, l, srU, scU, srV, scV, srW, scW, U, V, W, block_num);
        gemm_rec(m, n, l, srU, scU+n, srV+n, scV, srW, scW, U, V, W, block_num);
        gemm_rec(m, n, l, srU, scU, srV, scV+l, srW, scW+l, U, V, W, block_num);
        gemm_rec(m, n, l, srU, scU+n, srV+n, scV+l, srW, scW+l, U, V, W, block_num);
        gemm_rec(m, n, l, srU+m, scU, srV, scV, srW+m, scW, U, V, W, block_num);
        gemm_rec(m, n, l, srU+m, scU+n, srV+n, scV, srW+m, scW, U, V, W, block_num);
        gemm_rec(m, n, l, srU+m, scU, srV, scV+l, srW+m, scW+l, U, V, W, block_num);
        gemm_rec(m, n, l, srU+m, scU+n, srV+n, scV+l, srW+m, scW+l, U, V, W, block_num);
        
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i=srW; i<srW+m; i++)
            for(int j=scW; i<scW+l; j++)
                for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
                    W[i * m + j] += U[i * m + (k+scU)]*V[(k+srV) * n + j];
    }
}
'''
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You probably want `\`\`\`` instead of `'''`, i.e. upper backticks instead of single quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: compile your program with the `-g` option and debug it in `gdb`